# Rotating images on a circular path using CSS/SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I came across [Hugo Giraudel's excellent tutorial](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/04/02/items-on-circle/) on arranging images on a circle using SASS/CSS, and I am trying to take it another step further by animating the rotation of the circle of images. I have modified a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJbJyR) showing one of a variety of unsatisfactory results I am getting. The HTML is just an unordered list of five images:

```
<ul class='circle-container'>
  <li class="city">
    <a href='#'><img src='http://lorempixel.com/150/150/city'></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nature">
    <a href='#'><img src='http://lorempixel.com/150/150/nature'></a>
  </li>
  <li class="abstract">
    <a href='#'><img src='http://lorempixel.com/150/150/abstract'></a>
  </li>
  <li class="sports">
    <a href='#'><img src='http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/'></a>
  </li>
  <li class="food">
    <a href='#'><img src='http://lorempixel.com/150/150/food'></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

His SASS/CSS with some minor edits of mine:

```
/**
 * Mixin to put items on a circle
 * [1] - Allows children to be absolutely positioned
 * [2] - Allows the mixin to be used on a list
 * [3] - In case box-sizing: border-box has been enabled
 * [4] - Allows any type of direct children to be targeted
 */

@mixin putOnCircle( 
          $nb-items, //Number of items
          $circle-size, //Parent size
          $item-size, //Item size
          $class-for-IE: false //Base class name, false means use of pseudo-selectors
       ) {
  $item-size: 150px;
  $nb-items: 5; 
  $circle-size: 550px;
  $half-item:     $item-size / 2;
  $half-parent: $circle-size / 2;

  position: relative;               /* [1] */
  width:  $circle-size;
  height: $circle-size;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  list-style: none;                 /* [2] */ 
  @include box-sizing(content-box); /* [3] */ 

  > * {                             /* [4] */
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:  50%; 
    left: 50%;
    width:  $item-size;
    height: $item-size;
    margin: -$half-item;

    $angle: 360 / $nb-items;
    $rot: 0;
    @for $i from 1 to $nb-items+1 {

      // If no support for IE8-

      @if $class-for-IE == false {
        &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
          @include transform(rotate(#{$rot}deg) translate($half-parent) rotate(-#{$rot}deg));
        }
      }

      // If support for IE8-  

      @else {
        &.#{$class-for-IE}#{$i} {
          // If CSS transforms are not supported
          $mt: sin($rot * pi() / 180) * $half-parent - $half-item;
          $ml: cos($rot * pi() / 180) * $half-parent - $half-item;
          margin: $mt 0 0 $ml;
        }
      }
      $rot: $rot + $angle;
    }
  }
}

.circle-container {
  @include putOnCircle(8, 20em, 6em, false); 
  margin: 5em auto 0;
  border: solid 5px tomato;
  animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rot 8s infinite linear;

  a {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px tomato;
  }

  img { 
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    @include  filter(grayscale(100%));

    &:hover {
      @include filter(grayscale(0));
    }
  }
}
@keyframes rot {
  from {
    transform:        rotate(0deg)
                      translate(-275px)
                      rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
                      translate(-275px)
                      rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:        rotate(360deg)
                      translate(-275px)
                      rotate(-360deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
                      translate(-275px) 
                      rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rot {
  from {
    transform:        rotate(0deg)
                      translate(-275px)
                      rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
                      translate(-275px)
                      rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:        rotate(360deg)
                      translate(-275px) 
                      rotate(-360deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
                      translate(-275px) 
                      rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.city,
.nature,
.abstract,
.sports,
.food {
  /*animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
*/
}
```

In the code above (same as in the codepen), the images stay in their fixed positions, but the entire circle container rotates (revolves, really).

If I remove the animation on the circle-container ul:

```
.circle-container {
      @include putOnCircle(8, 20em, 6em, false); 
      margin: 5em auto 0;
      border: solid 5px tomato;
      /* animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
      -webkit-animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
      -moz-animation: rot 8s infinite linear; */
```

...and instead animate the list items (or the anchor elements, or the imgs):

```
.city,
    .nature,
    .abstract,
    .sports,
    .food {
      animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
      -webkit-animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
      -moz-animation: rot 8s infinite linear;
    }
```

I am then able to rotate (revolve) an image correctly around the circle, but only one image. The four other images seem to fall in line behind it. I am sure the solution is fairly simple, but I've tried every permutation I can think of, and it's been eluding me long enough that I thought I'd turn here for advice. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to solve this, without need to write different animations, is to use different timing for each one

```
.city {animation-delay: 0s; }
.nature {animation-delay: -1.6s; }
.abstract {animation-delay: -3.2s; }
.sports {animation-delay: -4.8s;}
.food {animation-delay: -6.4s;}
```

each delay is the total animation time divided by the number of elements and multiplyed by the element position

The delays are negative so that everything works from the beginning.

You should write a mixin using nth-child(n), but I don't know SASS enough for this. (sorry)

Comment: That solved it beautifully. I just had to remember to add the web prefixes to get it to work on my site (I'm using Chrome). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Could definitely write better mixin for this, but I would just create new animations for each image so the starting and ending angles are offset.

```
@-webkit-keyframes city-rot {
from {
transform:         rotate(45deg)
                   translate(-275px)
                   rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg)
                   translate(-275px)
                   rotate(-45deg);
}
to {
transform:         rotate(405deg)
                   translate(-275px) 
                   rotate(-405deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(405deg)
                   translate(-275px) 
                   rotate(-405deg);
}
}

.city {
  animation: city-rot 8s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: city-rot 8s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: city-rot 8s infinite linear;
}
```